# SQL Server 2012 Permanent dmy Date

Tags: sql-server, date, format

Been struggling with this for a while now.

I am busy migrating a program from an Informix database to a SQL Server database and I am having issues with the default date format.

The program and Informix database are set up to use dmy date formatting so I will need to change the SQL Server to use dmy date formatting as well.

Is it possible to do this from inside the Management Studio permanently?

Comment: you could just read the data in and format it correctly during the import?

Comment: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlserverfaq/2009/11/13/how-to-change-date-format-after-installing-sql-server/ - if you are sure you want to go that route.

Comment: @Tanner the software does all of it's date inserts using dmy so it wouldn't really be an option

Comment: @MikeMiller I've already made that change but it still returns results as ymd

Comment: @Trent well i would change the program then. What is the program written in? surely it has the capability to specify date formats.

Comment: @Tanner the program is written in Genero BDL and it does have that capability but it is massive, it's over 400 modules and I'm not risking bugs going to clients because of date formats